# Best way to store a big json file in a database (postgres or mongo)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, mongodb, postgresql

I want to download some open data (geodata) in JSON format.
The downloadable file is archived in `bz2` format and weights about 430 Mb. When uncompressed the `json` file weights about 3,2 Gb.

There is also the opportunity to download partial data corresponding to a single region (100 in total). In that case each file weighs about 4 Mb and once uncompressed give a `json` file of 24 Mb.

I plan to use those data in a rails application (currently using a postgres database).

Since the data is available in JSON format, I thought about integrating a mongodb database alongside my postgres database.
But I don't know if mongodb is able to load such a huge file eg. using `mongoimport`.
I'd heard about a limit of 8 or 16 Mb document size.. But is this limit corresponds to a single 'row' of the file or is the file corresponds to the whole document?

In that later case even with the partial files it will be impossible to use mongodb, right?
But since I also heard about `mongoid` to be "slow", I wonder if it can be better to 'load' those data in postgres itself, on its own table (or even on its own database).
If so how can I load those data?
I think about reading the file line by line with plain Ruby and populating the database in the `seed.rb` file. (I'm aware that it could take a very looong time though)

Can anyone tell me in my situation what could be the best choice?

---

*Some considerations:

I don't have any constraints.

I'm using docker containers.

Those data will be read only in order to feed some fields in the main app with an autocompletion feature.

I plan to update the data every week or so from newly downloaded files.*

Edit: The "fields" (I mean keys of the JSON file) I'm interested in are strings that can have several words (ie. space separated strings).
Ultimately I want to have the fastest lookup search upon beginning of the words (may it be in the middle of the string).
Maybe the choice could be limited based on the indexes possibilities offered by mongodb and postgres.
And for postgres, I could store those data in string fields or even "as is" in JSONB field regarding to which provide the fastest indexes.

Comment: Just a tip: Did you know PostgreSQL has geometric and geographic query keywords? You could (slowly) parse the Geo data out of your JSON, and then put it into your database with full awareness, ready to be SELECTed out.

Comment: Hi, Yep, I'm actually using PostGIS extension in my main app, but here with those data I'm only interested about string values (name of locations, streets, etc.). I'm really interested about querying those entire set in order to provide those string values.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using [JSON::Stream](https://github.com/dgraham/json-stream) this is best suited for huge JSON documents that won't fit in memory.

Or try to implement this [YAJL C Bindings for Ruby](https://github.com/brianmario/yajl-ruby)

Hope to help

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll probably use that parser (or another one) if I go with extracting the data from the JSON in order to put it in postgres (as a background job or within a `seed.rb` file. BTW, if so, I could either go with plain old relational string fields, or with JSONB field. I'll probably search using beginning of words inside those strings. I'llprobably choose the solution that has fastest index lookups..